# Obtaining previous versions of Mac OS X for testing

Tags: macos, osx-server

I'm porting some code to OSX and am in need of some copies of older OSX versions.  Does the Mac Developer program allow downloading of previous OSX versions?  A few forums mention it, but I've found conflicting/old info on this.  It doesn't appear to be here:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

I'm also aware of this post [Does the Mac Developer Program have old versions of Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629523/does-the-mac-developer-program-have-old-versions-of-mac-os-x), but this is now 3 years old. I'm aware some versions can be purchased on Amazon--would rather not go that route though unless necessary.  What is the common way to test OSX applications for backwards compatibility?

Thanks!

Comment: The old versions are there, exactly by this download link, starting from 10.5. Are you asking for even older ones?

Comment: No, 10.5+ is good enough. Can you give me an example title? I don't see them in the list.  I assume you have paid access to the OSX Dev Program?

Comment: "Mac OS X v10.5 Leopard 9A581". Leave only “OS X” checkbox checked, and type “10.5”, “10.6” into search field on the left.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know. I probably can't see it because my company has not paid for the Dev Program yet. Thank you!

Comment: @hamstergene when I search for 10.7 & 10.8, there're no dmg file for them. But 10.6 works this way.

Comment: @Gon As far as I can see Apple removed every master image. Only updates are available. You cannot download say 10.9 anymore.

Comment: @IvanNikitin I'm not finding this to be true right now (I know this is an old post; just making a memo for the future). Yesterday, 10.12 macOS Sierra released, and I see OS DMG files dating back to 10.3.9, but alas 10.11 El Capitan is notably absent. Maybe it will come back later.